# Check a proof that, besides $\varnothing$, no open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am teaching myself Munkres's Analysis on Manifolds and came across an exercise, stated in the title of this question. Please see my proof below and, if doable, criticize it.

That a set has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is meant here that one can cover the set by a collection of countably many $n$-rectangles the total content of which is less than any prescribed positive number.

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be open with $A \neq \varnothing$ and let $x \in A$. Then there is some $\delta > 0$ such that the ($n$-dimensional) neighborhood $N^{n}(x,\delta) \subset A$. If $A$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then so does $N^{n}(x,\delta)$. But, if $R$ is an $n$-rectangle inscribed to $N^{n}(x,\delta)$, then the boundary $\partial R$ of $R$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, so the $n$-rectangle $R$ does not have measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, a contradiction.

My native language is not English, so please refuse not to offer any advice also on this point.

Comment: Why do you need to talk about the boundary of $R$? Doesn't $R \subset N^n(x,\delta) \subset A$ suffice to show that $A$ has nonzero measure?

Comment: The idea is right, but you could have stopped once you noted that $A$ had a small open ball contained within it (which necessarily has nonzero measure by definition).

Comment: Yes, I see, thank you all. :)